# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module - Chrome Extension Manifest 3.00

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, import, manifest

I'm converting my manifest v2 Chrome extension to v3, and getting the error below when I imported a function from another javascript file, to background.js file;

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

background.js

```
import test_123 from './test.js';
```

test.js

```
export function test_123()
{
  alert('test ok');
}
```

manifest.js

```
  "background":{
    "service_worker": "background.js"
},
```

I have too many functions in the test.js file, so it's great if there is any way to import the whole test.js at once using something like require('./test.js')

Can anyone please point me in the right direction to identify the issue and solve it?

Comment: Add "type":"module" to "background" section in manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm Adding "type":"module" not worked for me.

Comment: Well, since it works normally I guess you either didn't reload the extension or there is a typo or you're looking at the old error, which you can clear by clicking the Clear all button.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the tip. I have already tried reloading the extension and reproducing the problem many times. But the result is still the same. Looking for another approach to solve it.

Comment: It's the only approach. Another possible mistake would be that you load background.js somewhere else.